# No events are recorded on Token page

Tags: erc-20, etherscan

I created a token on polygon and transferred it several times, but these events don't appear on token page, while they appear on Contract page.

- https://polygonscan.com/address/0x18592e4271F3145453A2aaC7E1E139EB1A75a293
- https://polygonscan.com/token/0x18592e4271F3145453A2aaC7E1E139EB1A75a293

Why no events are recorded on Token page?

Answer (score 0):

Notn100% sure but it might be related to your event definition.

In your `Transfer` event you are not marking the address fields as `indexed`.

According to the ERC-20 standard this is required. See:

- https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol#L75
- https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/

Comment: Oh, I see thanks. I followed eth-brownie's template, but it seems to be wrong. I'll feedback to the project. https://github.com/brownie-mix/token-mix/blob/master/contracts/Token.sol#L24-L25